# Href height incorrect when text-decoration: none and next to vertical aligned image

Tags: css, href, vertical-alignment

I have a link next to an image and it's vertical aligned to the image. When text-decoration is standard, the text link is perfectly in the middle.

[image]

If I change the text-decoration to none, the text stays in the same place, but without the underline which makes the text not look like it is centered vertically.

[image]

Seems like it's a bug of some sort but curious if any ideas.

Any ideas or am I just too picky?

Comment: http://www.blue-eyedesign.com/_test/text1.gif

Comment: http://www.blue-eyedesign.com/_test/text2.gif

Comment: The text _is correctly aligned_. Change the Home text to something with a character that goes down, like g/p/y etc (Candy?) and you will see that it is centered. It's just your eyes that's messing with you.

Comment: Guess so... it does seem to be where it needs to be it just "looks off."

Comment: Either go for ALL CAPS or just leave the `text-decoration` if you need perfect perception of symmetry. Most people won't even notice it anyway, I'd personally would let it slide.

Answer (score 0):

"If I change the text-decoration to none, the text stays in the same place, but without the underline"

And what do you want? **text-decoration:none** removes underline in any case.

Comment: I do not want the underline, but I want it vertically centered next to the image. Removing text decoration on the link makes it look like it is no longer aligned correctly.